# Not able to see the Label against which Auto Policy has been created

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, retention, office-dev-pnp, governance

I have followed below steps in order to create label and policy.

1. Create a new Retention labels

[image]

2. Publish Policy with "Auto-apply a label"

[image]

Now when I go back and see the published policy don't see which label is associated with the policy

[image]

Is there a way I can see which label is associated with this policy?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, it's in the settings. As the below picture shows. You could click "edit" to add labels.

[image]

Comment: This is true when you do not Auto Apply. If you publish with Auto Apply you will not see that detail.